# VisualBasic import excel to MySQL phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, vb.net, import, export

I Want to have a button in Visual Basic that will Import the excel file and be viewed in a ListView then save that Data into MySql Databased named "user_registration" with table named "login" and columns named "username,password,name,id,type"

Also i want to have a button that can print the data loaded in the listview from MySql phpmyadmin